# Why no WYSIWYG for comments?

Tags: feature-request, comments, code-formatting

I just noticed that, while you can do some formatting in comments to highlight code snippets, you're unable to see the results of that formatting as you're typing in the comment, which is not the case when typing in a question.

Comment: Please refrain from adding fluff to your question. [Do not use signature, taglines, or greetings.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior) And I give you a thorough meh on your request.

Comment: Comments are just third class citizens on the site, we don't want to actively encourage people actually use them for anything more than quick-fire feedback. That means no WYSIWYG.

Comment: The only things you need for effective commenting are: 1) wrap in `\`backticks\`` for inline code, and 2) link formatting `[link text](http://example.com/link/url)`.  Maybe 3) `_underscores for italics_` once in a while. Memorize these things, train your fingers, and you'll be fine.

Comment: Please don't use bold text in comments though. That is obnoxious.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Really?, I've often used *italics* (`*text*`) and **bold** (`**text**`) in certain circumstances for emphasis...

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Also don't forget the ever useful `[ask]` which I only learned recently but is an absolute lifesaver!!! - Demo: [ask]

Comment: @Lankymart I use italics to quote people or sites, but I stand by my opinion that bold has no place in comments (and indeed the community uses bold in comments exceedingly rarely)

Comment: @Lankymart Wow, I didn't know about the `[ask]` shortcut.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Then it shouldn't be allowed if it's frowned upon. Personally the only thing that I find offensive IS CAPITAL LETTERS IN A COMMENT as it denotes the commenter is shouting.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Yeah someone pointed that little gem out to me this week. I wonder if there are other "magic links"?... edit: [It appears there is](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94000/202529)!

Comment: To the people who down-voted my question: I would have preferred you simply left a comment about why you didn't think my suggestion was a good one. I think down-votes to suggestions discourage future suggestions...

Comment: @SheldonR. voting on Meta is different and is used to express disagreement with the post; the tooltip on the downvote button is misleading though.

Comment: @SheldonR. Meta works differently. Downvotes on posts marked "feature-request" show that users disagree with your proposal. (Note: Some people do carry this over to other tags. The main thing to remember is you don't lose rep on Meta, so don't take the downvotes too seriously.)

Comment: @Kendra Thanks for the clarification, Kendra. Not only am I new to posting on Meta, the phenomenon of being downvoted is also new to me, so I'm probably taking it more personally than I ought to...

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski but but you have used bold in your comments 4 times!! out of your 14879 comments. [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12954709/mysql-avoiding-subqueries/12954750#comment17561969_12954750)[2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12839241/how-you-send-email-with-php-where-the-sender-has-two-emails#comment17371818_12839241)[3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6944557/validating-a-form-for-only-letter-inputs/6944634#comment8279555_6944634)[4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6396813/php-header-not-redirecting#comment7497655_6396813) That's **0.02688%**

Comment: @chancea LoooOOOLLLL! And it appears I did it twice in Oct2012. I wonder what was up with that. And I wonder how many untold thousands of _deleted_ comments I have to drive that percentage even lower.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do see you intentions and it would something like so:

[image]

(*Note: I don't advise commenting like so, it's just an example to show some formatting.*)

Although it might be overkill. Comments are quick and simple, most of the time there is little to no formatting. While answers tend to be longer and more complex, where formatting is needed. For the most part if you mess-up your comment it's easy to just edit the comment and fix your mistake.

It may just get in peoples way other than help them, especially if the comment has not formatting to it. It could be helpful for a few cases, but it will not be for most.

Comment: Thanks for your response, Spencer. You're right in saying that most of the time formatting is not needed for comments, but I just used it for a comment for the first time, and at that time I noticed that lack of WYSIWG. Perhaps I'm misremembering, but it seems to me that when I first started using this site four years ago, that feature didn't exist for questions or answers, so I thought I'd made the suggestion to have it apply for comments as well. But apparently the community does not feel the same way, so I'll let it go. Thanks again...